# multidimensional array php move child

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have an multidimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [59] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 59
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => detalles de los
            [order] => 1

        )

    [60] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 60
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => Fechas varias
            [order] => 2

        )

    [62] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 62
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => seccion de fechas dependientes
            [order] => 3

        )

    [63] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 0
            [name] => tabbbbb
            [order] => 5
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [61] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 61

                            [parent_id] => 63
                            [name] => Números varios
                            [order] => 5

                        )

                    [70] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 70
                            [parent_id] => 63
                            [name] => tablas22
                            [order] => 6

                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [58] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 58
                                            [parent_id] => 70
                                            [name] => datos demograficos
                                            [order] => 4

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

and i want to remove the entry 70

```
[70] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 70
                            [parent_id] => 63
                            [name] => tablas22
                            [order] => 6
```

but i want the child [58]  to be the child of [61] and [70] to be the child of [61]

How should i do that? i tryed unset but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to move the entry or remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$child58 = $array[63]->children[70]->children[58];
unset($array[63]->children[70]->children);

$child70 = $array[63]->children[70];
unset($array[63]->children[70]);

$array[63]->children[61]->children = array(58 => $child58, 70 => $child70);
```

Comment: thank you so much i knew it was simple, now all i have to do it's to create a function that'll take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
unset($array[63]->children[70]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of `70` do this:

```
unset $yourArray[63]['children'][70];
```

You cannot easily change node key, so you'd need to clone it and unset old one, i.e. to "rekey" entry `58` to become `61`:

```
$yourArray[61] = $yourArray[58];
unset( $yourArray[58] );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a bit complicated, because you have a data structure that has to be moved, and you have actual data that represents the data structure as well, e.g. each stdClass has a parent_id property that points to somewhere useful.

Correcting your data structure might be easy, but this structure comes from somewhere, and you might be better of changing this source instead.

For the movements simply copy and delete.

First move [58] to the new place:

```
$array[63]->children[61]->children[58] = $array[63]->children[70]->children[58];
unset ($array[63]->children[70]->children[58]);
```

Then move 70:

```
$array[63]->children[61]->children[70] = $array[63]->children[70];
unset ($array[63]->children[70]);
```